# Get the enum value out from protobuf messages

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Here is a protobuf message definition:

```
message People {
  enum PeopleName {
    Alice = 100;
    Bob = 101;
    Cathy = 102;
  }
  optional PeopleName name = 1;
}
```

I would like to populate the name field based on some strings I created. E.g. in golang:

```
str := "Cathy"
```

How can I populate the "name" in the protobuf message?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Go protobuf generator emits a map of enum names to values (and vice versa). You can use this map to translate your string to enum value:

```
str := "Cathy"

value, ok := People_PeopleName_value[str]
if !ok {
    panic("invalid enum value")
}

var people People
people.Name = People_PeopleName(value)
```

Comment: This answer does not build with `syntax="proto3"` since then, the `Enum()` methiod is not generated. You need to remove the `.Enum()` from the last line.

Answer (score 4):

With proto3, from enum value to string, you can directly use:

```
name.String()
```

Comment: The question is asking the opposite, going from string to enum.